# Clear all kind of intervals

Tags: javascript, promise, setinterval, intervals

Imagine the scenario in which you have the main function which executes 2 functions which start intervals. These functions are imported as a NodeJS module and executed. Then in the main function after some time you clearIntervals. Also, note that there we'll be more intervals in the main function in the future.

So the main function is

```
(() => {
    const intervals = [];
    intervals.push(require('./simpleInterval')());
    intervals.push(require('./asyncInterval')());

    setTimeout(() => {
        intervals.forEach(id => clearInterval(id));
    }, 1200)
})();
```

One of these methods is simply

```
const intervalFoo = () => {
    return setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval simple')
    }, 500);
};

module.exports = intervalFoo;
```

but the second one contains some asynchronous code which can perform longer than interval gap but I don't want it to start before the previous "iteration" didn't finish. The solution in this kinda situation is to clear interval by id at the beginning and then reassign it at the end (but within the body) of interval. So the code of `asyncInterval.js` is:

```
const sleep = require('./utilities/sleep');

const intervalFoo = () => {
    let intervalId;
    const checkE2Interval = async() => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log('interval async');
        await sleep(120); //some long action
        return intervalId = setInterval(checkE2Interval, 100);
    };
    return intervalId = setInterval(checkE2Interval, 100); //returning id
};

module.exports = intervalFoo;
```

(sleep is just a promise which resolves after timeout time given as argument)

The issue about this is that I'm returning `intervalId` from `asyncInterval.js` also in the interval and my problem is that I don't know how am I suppose to clear this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide cancellation functions rather than providing raw handles, and pass your function an object with a flag it can check for whether it's been cancelled:

```
function mySetInterval(callback, ms, ...args) {
    let token = {
        cancelled: false
    };
    function wrapper(...args) {
        callback(token, ...args);
        if (!token.cancelled) {
            id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
        }
    }
    let id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
    return function cancel() {
        clearInterval(id);
        token.cancelled = true;
    }
}
```

Since `0` is an invalid timer ID, we can safely use it as a flag that the interval has been cancelled. Note that there is a *slight* difference between chained `setTimeout` (above) and `setInterval` (`setInterval`'s handling of the delay between intervals is...interesting.) Also note that nothing above prevents the function being called while it's paused on `sleep`. To do that, you'd have to have a guard and to have the function *specifically* support async functions:

```
function mySetInterval(callback, ms, ...args) {
    let token = {
        cancelled: false
    };
    let running = false;
    async function wrapper(...args) {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            await callback(token, ...args);
            running = false;
        }
        if (!token.cancelled) {
            id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
        }
    }
    let id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
    return function cancel() {
        clearInterval(id);
        token.cancelled = true;
    }
}
```

Use that function instead of `setInterval`.

In your async function, if it never has reason to stop itself:

```
const intervalFoo = () => {
    const checkE2Interval = async(token) => {
        console.log('interval async');
        await sleep(120); //some long action
        // If you had more logic here, you could short-circuit it by checking token.cancelled
    };
    return mySetInterval(checkE2Interval, 100); //returning id
};
```

If it *does* have reason to stop itself, save `cancel`:

```
const intervalFoo = () => {
    let cancel = null;
    const checkE2Interval = async(token) => {
        console.log('interval async');
        await sleep(120); //some long action
        // If you had more logic here, you could short-circuit it by checking token.cancelled
        // If you wanted not to continue the timer, you'd call cancel here
    };
    return cancel = mySetInterval(checkE2Interval, 100); //returning id
};
```

Then, where you need to cancel:

```
(() => {
    const cancellers = [];
    cancellers.push(require('./simpleInterval')());
    cancellers.push(require('./asyncInterval')());

    setTimeout(() => {
        cancellers.forEach(cancel => cancel());
    }, 1200)
})();
```

Live Example:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

function mySetInterval(callback, ms, ...args) {
    let token = {
        cancelled: false
    };
    function wrapper(...args) {
        callback(token, ...args);
        if (!token.cancelled) {
            id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
        }
    }
    let id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
    return function cancel() {
        clearInterval(id);
        token.cancelled = true;
    }
}

const intervalFoo = () => {
    let cancel = null;
    const checkE2Interval = async(token) => {
        console.log('interval async');
        await sleep(120); //some long action
        // If you had more logic here, you could short-circuit it by checking token.cancelled
        // If you wanted not to continue the timer, you'd call cancel here
    };
    return cancel = mySetInterval(checkE2Interval, 100); //returning id
};

(() => {
    const cancellers = [];
    cancellers.push(intervalFoo());

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Cancelling");
        cancellers.forEach(cancel => {
            cancel();
        });
    }, 1200)
})();
```

Live Example with the `running` flag:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

function mySetInterval(callback, ms, ...args) {
    let token = {
        cancelled: false
    };
    let running = false;
    async function wrapper(...args) {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            await callback(token, ...args);
            running = false;
        }
        if (!token.cancelled) {
            id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
        }
    }
    let id = setTimeout(wrapper, ms, ...args);
    return function cancel() {
        clearInterval(id);
        token.cancelled = true;
    }
}

const intervalFoo = () => {
    let cancel = null;
    const checkE2Interval = async(token) => {
        console.log('interval async');
        await sleep(120); //some long action
        console.log('awake');
        // If you had more logic here, you could short-circuit it by checking token.cancelled
        // If you wanted not to continue the timer, you'd call cancel here
    };
    return cancel = mySetInterval(checkE2Interval, 100); //returning id
};

(() => {
    const cancellers = [];
    cancellers.push(intervalFoo());

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Cancelling");
        cancellers.forEach(cancel => {
            cancel();
        });
    }, 1200)
})();
```

---

You can generalize this further, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I've changed my `main.js` and `asyncInterval.js` to your code https://gist.github.com/d0peCode/cc8d306a7b9561a57f6d1696f2a111aa and I'm getting error `TypeError: cancel is not a function` from `if(cancel) cancel();`

Comment: What do you mean? I'm runing `main.js` in my IDE. Also in `mySetInterval` function you assign interval id to `id` variable and then you clean `token.id` I dont understand

Comment: I've created demo in node.js playground on codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-merkle-krimg

Comment: So i've fixed the typo but now it's not consoling string every 120ms because it seems that `cancel` is always true (function)

Comment: @dopeCode - As I said (in a comment I *just* deleted, having updated the answer), there was another issue. I've fixed it now, see the revised answer, which features a live copy.

Comment: When you click run code snippet button you see that it executed 11 times every 100ms (or so) so now it doesn't actually wait for asynchronous code. If you run this code https://gist.github.com/d0peCode/708016b96965cbf82cc81c96d0fed85c you will see that it console `'interval async'` only 5 times before consoling `'1200ms elapsed'` because it wait for promise inside - (100ms + 120ms) * 5 = 1100ms. So sixth iteration is after 1200ms.

Comment: @dopeCode - See that bit where I talk about the `running` flag? But actually, that alone won't work. You'd have to have a specific version of `mySetInterval` designed to only support async functions.

Comment: yup but this `running` flag _guard_ as you called it doesn't fix it :(

Comment: @dopeCode - Right, as I said above, it need a tiny further tweak, which I've done now.